# Submitting a build for review while another build is already in ready to publish?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I had a build (let's call it version 1.0) approved and is now sitting in Ready to Publish (managed publishing on). I don't want to release this build until Monday, but I do want to submit a new build (version 2.0) for review over the weekend, so I can release that build later next week.

If I submit a new build (2.0) for review, while the first build (1.0) is already sitting in Ready to Publish, will build 1.0 be removed from Ready to Publish, or will I still be able to release 1.0 on Monday while waiting for 2.0 to be approved?

Tried finding supporting documentation online, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first build will sit in 'ready to publish' until the new build is approved. When the new build is approved, as far as I know it will take the other build's place in 'ready to publish' if you haven't published it yet.